# Asp.Net MVC custom controls - container

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to make helper in Asp.Net MVC to wrap other html like this:

```
<div class="lightGreyBar_left">
    <div class="lightGreyBar_right">

        <!--Content-->
        <h3>
            Profiles</h3>
        <div class="divOption">
            <%= Html.ActionLinkWithImage("Create new", "add.png", Keys.Actions.CreateProfile, "add")%>
        </div>
        <!--Content-->

    </div>
</div>
```

So that helper will render containing divs and content that is passed to helper method as parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the forms helper methods. They provide syntax like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <p>Form contents go here.</p>
<% } %>
```

The pattern for implementing this sort of HTML helpers is slightly more involved than the usual "just return a HTML string" type helpers. Basically, your helper method will `Response.Write` the opening tag(s) when it is called and return some custom object that implements `IDisposable`. When the return value is disposed, it should `Response.Write` the closing tag(s).

Here is a working example:

```
public static MyContainer WrapThis(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("<div><div>");
    return new MyContainer(html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response);
}

public class MyContainer : IDisposable
{
    readonly HttpResponseBase _httpResponse;
    bool _disposed;

    public MyContainer(HttpResponseBase httpResponse)
    {
        _httpResponse = httpResponse;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            _disposed = true;
            _httpResponse.Write("</div></div>");
        }

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to rewrite your view to this:

```
<% using (Html.WrapThis()) { %>
    <h3>Profiles</h3>
    <div class="divOption">
        <%= Html.ActionLinkWithImage("Create new", "add.png", Keys.Actions.CreateProfile, "add")%>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: "WrapThis" needs to be in a static class.. That is not obvious in this example.

Comment: After looking at this it is incorrect.  Doing this will write the contents to the top of the page.   It should be helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(...).  Also WrapThis needs to be in a static class, and the MyContainer method should have HtmlHelper as an argument, and not an HttpResponseBase.